# ArrayCache does not exist in Symfony 5.0.*

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can't seem to solve this problem.
After updating my dependencies, I have an error in the `ArrayCache` of Doctrine.

> In ContainerBuilder.php line 1103: 
>  Class "Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache" does not exist

I am using Symfony 5.0.*

```json
// composer.json
...
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
"doctrine/cache": "^2.1",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.0",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated out in the [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-cache/en/2.1/index.html#deprecation-notice) the doctrine/cache library has been deprecated:

> Please note that doctrine/cache is deprecated and no longer maintained. The last version to include cache drivers is 1.11. The 2.x major release series only provides the interfaces for libraries that need to maintain backward compatibility. For all cache uses, we suggest relying on PSR-6 or PSR-16 instead and using a cache library that supports those interfaces.

I think using the [Symfony cache component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html) is the best solution now